# GenericJDBCException when trying to put Unique constraint

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring and Hibernate (HSQLDB) and as soon as I put

```
 @Column(unique = true) on a property
```

I get

`could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement`

every other constraint works fine [here's the github](https://github.com/Kadyen/AccountMonitor) if anyone needs it.
I'm very confused because this didn't occur when I was doing my previous project and there's not really much information on the internet about it. maybe it's really simple but I can't see it.

EDIT: [additional log](http://pastebin.com/Xk5XtvSK) As you can see, value is being inserted then it encounters unique violation and returns nullpointerexception. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot 1.3.0 has a dependency on HSQLDB 2.3.3.
HSQLDB has a bug that will throw a NullpointerException when a duplicate constraint violation occurs.

https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1406/
Bug text is as follows:

```
A null pointer exception is thrown in IndexAVLMemory when a unique constraint is violated:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVLMemory.insert(IndexAVLMemory.java:236)
at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.indexRow(RowStoreAVL.java:231)
... 44 more
The old and correct behavior was to get a SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException in such a case.
```

I recommend you exclude HSQL DB 2.3.3 and add an explicit dependency on 2.3.2.

Comment: The link for this answer didn't work for me, but if you use the latest version (2.3.4) this is fixed as well.  Thanks @JamesR!